# Strings are never equal when they should be

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a script which quizzes users on language vocabulary.

Here it is so far:

```
while read line
do
  trans -s es -brief "$line"
  read -r answer < /dev/tty
  echo -en "\e[2A"; echo -e "\e[0K\r$line"
  say -v Jorge "$line"
  if ["$answer" == "$line"]; then
    echo -en "\e[1A"; echo -e "\e[0K\rcorrect"
  else
    echo -en "\e[1A"; echo -e "\e[0K\rwrong"
  fi
done
```

and when run (the file passed via stdin can look like [this](http://pastebin.com/Nnw5ydyu)):

[image]

No matter what I enter, for some reason bash is printing `wrong` even though it should be correct.

Comment: @andlrc I already tried this: `["$answer\n" == "$line"]` but it changed nothing. I will try what you just proposed though.

Comment: That not what I said though, `["$answer" == "$line"]` -> `[ "$answer" = "$line" ]` or `[[ "$answer" = "$line" ]]`

Comment: @andlrc I just tried what you said and it hasn't worked. That command changed nothing from my previous observations. Sorry for maybe assuming some stuff, I am still _very_ new to bash :P